# VTiger Framework: Portal Dashboard Tags issue

Tags: listview, tags, character, workflow, vtiger

I installed VTiger framework. Created Work flow in Main dashboard. This effected the portal dashboard and removed tags and special characters('<', '>', '&') in portal list view. I deleted the created work flow. But the error not solved.

[image]

Comment: Post the error and the offending code

Comment: http://zonupsoftware.com/case.jpg  please review this link

Comment: _What_ error is not solved?